# Tikz: Correct arrows at the end of parametric curves?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=4]
\draw[domain=0:0.4, smooth, variable=\t, samples=200, ->] plot({(1/sqrt(2)*(\t-\t^3)},
{(1/sqrt(2)*(\t+\t^3)});
\draw[domain=0:0.4, smooth, variable=\t, samples=200, ->] plot({\t}, {-\t^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Hi the arrows will only point up at the end of my parametric curves. Is there a way I can fix this?

Edit: Removing the smooth option fixed it. I thought I needed that for obvious reasons. Thanks, Jesse!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Your code produces this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CNxZn.png  for me. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: I am getting the same strange orientation of the arrows at the end of the curve. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The extensive test shows that removing the `smooth` option makes the problem away.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}%[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=4]
\draw[domain=0:0.4, smooth, variable=\t, samples=200, ->] plot({(1/sqrt(2)*(\t-\t^3)},
{(1/sqrt(2)*(\t+\t^3)});
\draw[domain=0:0.4, smooth, variable=\t, samples=200, ->] plot({\t}, {-\t^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=4]
\draw[domain=0:0.4, variable=\t, samples=200, ->] plot({(1/sqrt(2)*(\t-\t^3)},
{(1/sqrt(2)*(\t+\t^3)});
\draw[domain=0:0.4, variable=\t, samples=200, ->] plot({\t}, {-\t^3});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I experienced so many problems with the `smooth` key in the past, so I try to avoid it at any cost. Another strange interference is between `smooth` and `decorate`.

Comment: Valid yet perplexing solution. :-)